# Representations theory of Groups with compact quotient

Tags: rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a locally profinite group and $H$ a closed normal subgroup of $G$, with $G/H$ a profinite group.

If $\rho$ is an irreducible (smooth) representation of $G$ what can we say about the restriction of $\rho$ to $H$? (Do we have Clifford theory, it's completely reducible)